# What is "esxcli network nic attachment add" used for in vSphere 7.0+?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

In vSphere 7.0's [doc](https://code.vmware.com/docs/11743/esxi-7-0-esxcli-command-reference/namespace/esxcli_network.html) it has a new CLI command:

- **Command:** `esxcli network nic attachment add`
- **Description:** Attach one uplink as a branch to a trunk uplink with specified VLAN ID.
- **Options:**

  - `--branch | -b`

    The name of the NIC to be attached as branch uplink. (required)
  - `--trunk | -t`

    The name of the NIC to be configured as trunk uplink. (required)
  - `--vlan-id | -v`

    The vlan ID for the branch uplink. Valid values: integer in the range 1-4094 (required)
  - `--help`

    Show the help message.

It's confusing to me what it does by *attach*ing one uplink to another uplink. Anyone knows a use case for this?

Comment: It's right there, in the description. It's is for [trunk configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunking).

Comment: it does not look the same as Link Aggregation or VLAN trunking even though it's using the terms "trunk" and "branch". based on the cli help, the "branch" uplink must be associated with one single vlan id. why not just add the "branch" uplink to a vss/vds and create a portgroup for that vlan?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you more, but there is an example mentioned:
https://www.virten.net/2020/04/new-esxcli-commands-in-vsphere-7-0/